# Post Form data from extjs4.2 to Spring Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, extjs, extjs4.2

Here is my extjs 4.2.1 data store :

```
Ext.define('APP.store.CompanyStore', {
extend  : 'Ext.data.Store',
requires: 'APP.model.Company',
model   : 'APP.model.Company',
proxy: {
        type    : 'ajax',
        url     : 'searchP.html',
        actionMethods :{read:'POST'},
        reader  : {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
       }
}
```

Here is my action on Submit :

```
    var pname   = Ext.getCmp('pname ').getValue();
    var SearchObj   = Ext.getCmp('searchForm').getValues();
    SearchObj.pname =pname;
    var store = Ext.getStore('APP.store.CompanyStore');
    store.load({
        params:{
            "SearchObj"  :Ext.encode(SearchObj)
        },
        callback: function(records, operation, success) {
            // the operation object
            // contains all of the details of the load operation
            console.log(records);
        }
    });
```

My problem :

> The object is not getting mapped to the POJO defined at server side in my Spring controller.What may be the problem.

My Spring Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchP", method = RequestMethod.POST)

    public @ResponseBody String searchP(@RequestBody Company company){

            System.out.println("pname"+company.getPName()); //getting null.Not getting actual value.

            return "item";

    }
```

Comment: For Spring to map a form post to a Bean, you have to match up the "name" attributes of your inputs with the values of the object you are attempting to create.  I don't know ExtJS, but you should be able to look at the request and figure out if the parts are in the proper place.  It may help to see the form code and the Company object as well.

Comment: Thanks @CodeChimp for your reply.I have resolved this issue.As you said I checked the name mappings.It was same.I,instead of using "@RequestBody" used "@RequestParam".Accepted it as json string(as one parameter) and manually converted it to the Company bean in my spring controller.